# Sorting an Integer list as if it were a String list in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a simple array of integers and I want to sort them but by String rules

**Example:** `{1, 7, 43, 15, 2, 12} -> {1, 12, 15, 2, 43, 7}`

I looked around and found `Integer.toString(int)` and `String.valueOf(int)` but that requires to make a new String array and convert them individually and sort it and convert it back to Integer and reassign it. Also, a Comparator I presume wouldn't be much different.

So are there more ways to do this?

Comment: Write your own Comparator

Comment: Convert all, sort, convert all back is the easiest way to do this. I'd go with that if I were you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two straight forward choices are:

- creating a `List<String>` from your `List<Integer>`, to then sort that String list, and turn it back into an Integer list in the end.
- using a custom comparator

The **major** difference: when you create list of strings initially, then you have to do that transformation Integer -> String ... exactly *once* per input number.

When you do that within the comparator, then you are doing it probably much more often! As you will be using a `Comparator<Integer, Integer>` ... which will always need to turn both arguments into Strings. Or do the relatively *expensive* math to determine the "length" of the input numbers.

Beyond that: unless we are talking about code that works on millions of numbers; or that is called a thousands of time each minute ... worrying about *performance* is simply wrong. Worry about the readability of your code; and the effort required to maintain it in the future.

Finally: if you see this as a challenge how to solve this problem using "interesting" ways; one other solution: you could use some `Pair<String, Integer>` class; with the String generated from the Integer number. Now you put those into a List, and use a comparator to sort on the String part of the Pair. Then you don't need another conversion; you simply walk the pairs, and you fetch the Integer numbers from each pair. But again, that is micro-performance-management and is "for the fun" only.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using a custom `Comparator`, based on the `String` representation of the integers :

```
Integer[] intArray = { 1, 7, 43, 15, 2, 12 };

Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(final Integer o1, final Integer o2) {

        return String.valueOf(o1).compareTo(String.valueOf(o2));
    }

};

Arrays.sort(intArray, comparator);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Comment: Oh, great, for some reason I didn't think that I only need to compare their values in the Comparator. Thanks.

Comment: Also take note of what @GhostCat says in his answer.

Comment: Yeah that was useful information. I can't mark both your answers green so I'll mark his for people who come in the future.

Comment: No problem, it is quite elaborate :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll still go with this

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 7, 43, 15, 2, 12);
List<Integer> orderedList= list.stream()
                               .map(String::valueOf)
                               .sorted()
                               .map(Integer::parseInt)
                               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That looks fancy.

Answer (score 1):

just another way, this time using the lambda power of java8

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 7, 43, 15, 2, 12);
l.sort((x, y) -> x.toString().compareTo(y.toString()));
System.out.println(l);
```

Output:

> **[1, 12, 15, 2, 43, 7]**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). You can keep it generic if you w ant to use it for other types as well:

```
class StringComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
  @Override
  public int compare(T first, T second) {
    // compare String representations
    return first.toString().compareTo(second.toString());
  }
}
```

Then, you can sort:

```
Integer[] a = {1; 2; 3; 11; 22}
Arrays.sort(a, new StringComparator<Integer>());
```